# Escaping all POST/GET parameters in ASP/ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, sql, escaping

I am a PHP developer trying to solve a problem in ASP/ASP.net (.aspx). We have a very old application that is having many security issues (on multiple pages, everywhere, big mess).

To solve this problem, I was thinking on adding some code to the top of every page to escape any POST/GET request before getting it processed by the application.

If it was PHP, I would prepend a PHP file (using .htaccess - auto_preppend) and basically do:

```
foreach($_POST as $myval => $anything)
{
    $_POST[$myval] = htmlspecialchars($_POST[$myval]);
    .. other escaping ..
}
```

Is there such a thing in ASP? Just want to escape any user input before passing to that mess of code that nobody wants to touch :(

Answer (score 3):

Is this ASP or ASP.NET? Different beasts entirely. If you're using .NET you could use something like:

in VB

```
For Each item In Request.Form.Keys
    newVal = Server.HtmlEncode(Request.Form(item))
Next
```

or C#

```
foreach (var item in Request.Form.Keys) {
    var newVal = Server.HtmlEncode(Request.Form(item));
}
```

Comment: Sorry, yes, it is ASP.net (.aspx) pages. I am not very familiar with the Microsoft platform at all :( So the HTMLEncode == htmlspecialchars in PHP?

Comment: Yep, pretty much the same thing. Docs here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3te6wfz.aspx

Answer (score 0):

From an individual control perspective, this might help: [Prevent special characters in a TextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3610188/prevent-special-characters-in-a-textbox)

If you are wanting to protect your entire form from script-injection attacks then take a look at RequestValidation: http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/request-validation