# Restrict user when he enters * character in text field in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there any way to restrict user from entering * key in text field.

I have textfield where * is not allowed, so how can I explicitly disable that * key when user enter in the particular text field.

Thanks.

Comment: Not with C# - this is a job for JavaScript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent special characters in a TextBox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3610188/prevent-special-characters-in-a-textbox)

Comment: It's perfectly possible to do with C# @MattiVirkkunen. It's just a bit out of date these days to use the post back model

Comment: @Liam: You're probably thinking of server-side validation. From what I understood he wanted to prevent the user from entering the character in the first place. Of course you're still going to need the server side validation too.

Comment: True. In that case your correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Javascript` for restricting `*` on keypress.

Then find the ASCII keycode of `*` on keypress and restrict it. And *[`ASCII keycode for * is 42.`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000520.html)*

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function IsAsterik(e) {            
        var keyCode = e.which ? e.which : e.keyCode
        var ret = (keyCode != 42)
        document.getElementById("error").style.display = ret ? "none" : "inline";
        return ret;
    }
</script>
```

**Textbox**

```
<input type="text" id="text1" runat="server" onkeypress="return IsAsterik(event);" 
        ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;" />
<span id="error" style="color: Red; display: none">* not allowed</span>
```

### **[`Find a demo here`](http://codepen.io/Ullas303/pen/EKMxMB)**

Comment: this is the only good answer, though I wouldn't call the method IsNumeric

Answer (score -1):

In C# on textbox key up event add this code

```
private void textBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
     string val = textBox1.Text;
     if(val.IndexOf('*')>-1)
     {
         textBox1.Text = val.Substring(0, val.Length - 1);
         if (val.Length>0)
            textBox1.SelectionStart = val.Length - 1;
          return;
     }
}
```

Happy Coding. :)

Comment: Oh god, don't use a keyup. This is a terrible idea, see below

Comment: May I know the reason? @Liam

Comment: Because everytime someone hit's a key it will postback. This will at best be a terrible user experience at worst will make you UI unusable

Comment: Got it. Thanks. Should use javascript if works in asp.net. I wrote code for window application.

Comment: Yes, this will work in windows in web, terrible idea