# Can you Format input from a text box in C# without a masked text box?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to format many text boxes in my C# web application some to accept 13 numbers some to accept 10 numbers and some to accept a combination like "IS112" I haven't been able to find anything that wasnt a masked text box using AJAX Extensions and am just checking to see if there is any way before I have to add the extension and remake and ID my text boxes.

Comment: You can use custom validators and regex

Comment: Do you control the environment? You might look at some of the new <input /> types implemented in HTML5. They're not all standard, yet, though.

Comment: would I place the regex right in the generated method for the text box? sorry I'm new to c# and creating a web application. I'm working on my capstone and this is one of the last things I have to do and it's slowing me down.

Comment: For integer validations - [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427629/asp-net-validation-to-make-sure-textbox-has-integer-values)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent special characters in a TextBox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3610188/prevent-special-characters-in-a-textbox)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtBox" runat="server" MaxLength="13"></asp:TextBox>
This is a text Box
 <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1"runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtBox"
ValidationExpression="^(\d{0,13})$" ErrorMessage="*Invalid Text Length:" text="*" Display="Dynamic" />
```